# WPF - Diamond-shaped button style with text inside

Tags: c#, wpf

How to make diamond-shaped button **style** with text that is displayed **horizontally** like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTOAB.png)

I did this, but don't know what to do next:

```
<Style x:Key="Button">
        <Setter Property="Button.Height" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="Button.Width" Value="40"/>           

        <Setter Property="Button.RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>            
</Style>
```

Comment: A transform is not a good approach for this problem for a LOT of reasons (performance, layout, clipping.)  Especially since you don't want the text to rotate, meaning you're going to have reskin the button regardless.  You might want to check out some video tutorials on how to do this.  My WPF is rusty, but changing the basic shape of a button without messing up the rest of the page is actually a little tricky to do well, and as it stands, your question might be too broad.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to not define your text content utilizing the `Button` control `Content` dependency property, but instead define your `Text` in a separate control such as the obvious `TextBlock`, since the content is also going to be rotated 45 degrees due to the render transform.

In your style, if you want your button to look exactly as the one in the link that you provided, you should also set the following dependency properties: `BorderThickness`, `BorderBrush` (Black) and `Background` (White).

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Place the pair Button/TextBlock inside the same layout area, and overlap the Button control with the TextBlock. Depending on the dimensions to which you set your `Button` control element, you can easily play with the `Margin` dependency property on the `TextBlock` control and put it exactly on your desired place. 
This would be my option if I were to choose a Grid as the layout container for these 2 control definitions.

If instead I choose to use a Canvas, I would utilize the attached properties `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`, like this

```
<Canvas Margin="100,0,0,0">
    <Button x:Name="myButton"/>
    <TextBlock Text="TextTextText" Canvas.Left="-40" Canvas.Top="60"/>
</Canvas>
```

You could actually have an `CLR property` calculating these two distances, based on your `Button` dimensions and perform `binding` to these two attached properties. For this situation, I set those values for the offsets for a Button dimension of (Width: 100, Height: 100).

PS. The code provided is working for UWP (I am more used to it :p), so I am not particularly 100% sure that the solution works right of the bat for WPF.

Comment: Is it possible, to set the text slope in the style?

Answer (score 0):

You could try rotating the button by 45 degrees like you did and then adding a TextBlock which is rotated -45 degrees to keep it horizontal. I'm sure there are better ways but this should work.

```
<Button>
    <TextBlock Text="Testing">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-45"/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```